# macbook pro ubuntu integrated gpu performance

Tags: ubuntu, macintosh, gpu, refind

I'm trying to get ubuntu 18.04.2 to use my the integrated GPU of my macbook pro (mid 2014)

In the process I've discovered that when booted normally, the device is not even visible in `lspci`.
The only result is the nvidia graphics card

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M Mac Edition] (rev a1)
```

but then I boot the system with the `spoof_osx_version=10.9` option set in [refind](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html)

at which point they both become discoverable `lspci`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 08)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M Mac Edition] (rev a1)
```

However the whole system becomes incredibly slow, using either integrated or discrete gpu (switched via [gpu-switch](https://github.com/0xbb/gpu-switch)).
It's much slower than simply using my discrete gpu without the `spoof_osx_version` in my refind.conf.

I would love to have the added battery life of a properly functioning integrated gpu.
How can I go about fixing this?